# Error "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to get profiles from database using EntityFramework.

But every time I am getting the following error:

The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

My code :

```
private readonly IDbContextDMO _globalContext;
```

```
using (IProfilService profilService = _profilService ?? new ProfilService(Settings, _globalContext))
{
      //doing something here
}
```

```
var r_GetHigherProfileAsync = await _profilService.GetHigherProfileByIntervenantIdAsync();
```

I can't understand why I am getting this error. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Well, are you using the same context multiple times? Does the `Dispose` method in `ProfilService` dispose of the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by deleting the "using" and keeping the content //doing something here.

Answer (score 1):

You are `using` the `ProfilService`, which means as soon as "doing something here" completes, `Dispose()` is called, which disposes `_globalContext` (from the comment).

You should consider your intended lifetimes. If the db-context is intended to outlive any single `ProfilService`, then `ProfilService` should not be disposing it (or should at least have a flag to control that).

Similarly, if `_profilService` is not null, you'll currently be disposing it *even though* it isn't obvious that it should now die; so perhaps:

```cs
var profilService = _profilService;
bool disposeSvc = false;
try {
    if (profilService is null)
    {    // temporary just for this call
         profilService = new ProfilService(Settings, _globalContext);
         disposeSvc = true;
    }
    //doing something here
} finally {
    if (disposeSvc) profilService?.Dispose();
}
```

---

Alternatively and much more simply: use more transient lifetimes, rather than keeping things globally. Then you *can* usually dispose readily.